# Using iText with JBoss 7 Java EE project

Tags: java, jsf, jboss, itext, seam

How to use iText with JBoss 7 Java EE project?

I created a Java EE Project using JBoss Tools
Group Id: org.jboss.tools.example
Artifact Id: multi

I'm now trying to use iText to create a PDF from my Bean

```
<p:document xmlns:p="http://jboss.com/products/seam/pdf">                                                      

  This only prints plaintext                                                                                          

</p:document>
```

According to JBoss Wiki (http://docs.jboss.org/seam/1.1.5.GA/reference/en/html/itext.html) I need jboss-seam-pdf.jar and the iText.jar - can I use Maven for this? The dependency I found broke my project.

If anyone could help me set up iText with JBoss 7 I'd highly appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

> can I use Maven for this? The dependency I found broke my project.

Maven is always appreciated as dependency management mechanism.

The example you see is a sample froject using the old Seam framework >= 2 which is useful for Java EE 5 (now we have CDI). To use the seam-pdf module you have to integrate the Seam2 framework but it's obsolete now. My recommendation is instead of using declarative way to build PDF, use the iText API and build a pdf yourself. iText documentation is quite good and there is a book and many examples over the internet.

> If anyone could help me set up iText with JBoss 7 I'd highly appreciate it

After you have created the war project add iText as maven dependency to your .pom file and you are ready to go.